# How do I print out the count of unique matches with grep?

Tags: regex, sorting, count, grep

Lets say I have millions of packets to look through and I want to see how many times a packet was sent to a certain port number.

Here are some of the packets:

```
10:27:46.227407 IP 85.130.236.26.54156 > 139.91.133.120.60679: tcp 0
10:27:46.337038 IP 211.142.173.14.80 > 139.91.138.125.56163: tcp 0
10:27:46.511241 IP 211.49.224.217.3389 > 139.91.131.47.6973: tcp 0
```

I want to look through the 2nd port number here so:

60679, 53163, 6973, etc

So I can use:

```
grep -c '\.80:' output.txt
```

To count all the times port 80 was used. But is there a way for it to display all the ports that were used and how many times it was found in this file. Something like this and preferable sorted too so I can see which ports were used most often:

```
.80: - 54513
.110: - 12334
.445: - 412
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

See [`uniq -c`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq). You'll want to pull out the bit you want, sort the result, pipe thru uniq, sort the output. Something like this maybe:

```
egrep '\.[0-9]+:' output.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Clarification: I've used grep here because it's not clear what your output.txt format looks like, but you'll want to actually cut out the port number bit, perhaps via `cut` or `awk`.

Edit: To get the port, you can cut once on a period and then again on a colon:

```
cut -d. -f10 < output.txt | cut -d: -f1
```

(Or any one of a dozen other ways to accomplish the same thing.) That will give you an unsorted list of ports. Then:

```
cut -d. -f10 < output.txt | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I'm having trouble with cut. Is there a way to cut only using regular expression? Because the port number isn't in the same column and spacing every time.

Comment: Cut does not use regex. Edit your question and add a few example lines so we can see the format.

Comment: Ok I edited it some examples. What would you recommend I use then?

Comment: Huge help! I really appreciate it