# Finding and counting unique files accessed on a web server

Tags: linux, logging, sed, grep, command

I'm sorting through an access log file attempting to locate any lines that have unique files that were requested and accessed. My log file is in this format:

```
66.249.75.4 - - [14/Dec/2015:08:25:18 -0600] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 1012 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.75.4 - - [14/Dec/2015:08:25:18 -0600] "GET /~robert/class2.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 1012 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
(so on and so forth...)
```

My goal is to locate any of these 14,000+ lines that have accessed a unique file (`"GET / etc... etc..."`) from the web server, and count how many of these are present. I want to get rid of any of these calls that accessed the same page, and only count those that are not duplicates. I'm very new to the linux command line and I'm working with familiarizing myself with some of these commands and their abilities.

I've toyed with trying it with `grep`, piping `cat` into `sort -k 7 -u`, `uniq`, and a few others. None of these seem to give me my expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print out the count of unique matches with grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301063/how-do-i-print-out-the-count-of-unique-matches-with-grep)

Comment: I did find and look over that thread. I'm looking for input on how to setup my grep pattern to match these strings and only compare those in order to use `uniq`, as opposed to looking at the whole line and trying to compare those to each other. I only want to compare what is within my grep pattern and find unique values among those. Is `grep '\"GET /*\"' access_log` proper for what i'm looking for? Or is that too ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for the count, you can use:

```
cut -d' ' -f6-7 logs.txt  | sort -u | wc -l
```